# Table content margin

Tags: css, html-table, margin

I made a table inside a box. By default the table is centered inside a box, but I want it to touch the bottom border of the box. I have two cells in a row and both have pictures I need to make they touch borders in the bottom.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="design.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box1">      
        <table width="614" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr align="center">
                <td>                        
                    <img src="TL.png">
                </td>
                <td width="1" class="vertical"></td>
                <td>
                    <img src="TR.png">
                </td>                   
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
.box1{      
width: 614px;   
margin: 0px;
position:absolute;
border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
padding: 20px;
border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
overflow: auto;}
.vertical{
border-right: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
width: 0px; 
height: 250px;
float: left;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #ffffff;}
```

Can someone explain please?

Comment: The solution is to modify your code until it works right.

Comment: The thing is, I'm making a template where images of various sizes will be. Adjusting margins for every image/text every time will take too much time.

I'm asking if there's any fast way to margin whole table or at least rows, but not each cell at the time.

Comment: Please, post some code... it's impossible to answer as it is now. Better if you create a fiddle with sample images taken from google.

Comment: Here you go. I want whole table to move to the very edge/border of the box in the bottom.

Comment: Here you go: code added, answer received ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of the `padding` in `.box1`.

Since the current value is `padding : 20px`, this applies a `20px` to all sides. If you don't want the `padding` on bottom, change it to :

```
padding : 20px 20px 0; /* padding : top left-right bottom */
```

CSS :

```
.box1 {      
    width: 614px;   
    margin: 0px;
    position:absolute;
    border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
    padding: 20px 20px 0;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yvvyP/1/) for demo.

**EDIT :**
For dynamically setting the height of `.vertical`, use this jQuery :

```
$('.vertical').each(function () {
    var currentLine = $(this),
        prevImgHeight = currentLine.prev('td').find('img').height(),
        nextImgHeight = currentLine.next('td').find('img').height(),
        lineHeight = (prevImgHeight > nextImgHeight) ? prevImgHeight : nextImgHeight;

    currentLine.css('height', lineHeight + 'px');
});
```

This will set the `height` of the line equal to greater of the two adjacent `img`

Comment: Thanks is worked for me now! But now my box gets a side-slider due to content height. How can I determine the hight to change with the box content dinamically?

Comment: What do you mean by side-slider ? Since the `height` is not specified for `.box1`, it'll automatically take the content height.

Comment: Sorry, yes I added that after I posted the code. I have a vertical line to seperate two cells. But height:100%; won't work, since it has to get the value from parent. 
I'll have many different boxes on my page with different content and I want that to be dynamic, so I don't have to deal with specifying the size all the time. How do I get that line and a box to draw dynamically?